# Integrate $\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{2}{\cos^{6}(x) + \sin^{6}(x)} dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Integrate $$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{2}{\cos^{6}(x) + \sin^{6}(x)} dx$$
I have tried to do Tangent substitution, but there is huge power.
What method is better to use here?

Comment: Just to clarify, by $cosx^6$ you mean $(\cos x)^6$ right?

Comment: You might start with $$1=(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)^3=\cos^6x+\sin^6x+3\sin^2x\cos^2x.$$ Then...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{2}{\cos^6 x + \sin^6 x} dx
&=8\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\cos^6 x + \sin^6 x} dx\\
&=8\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{(\cos^2 x  + \sin^2 x)(\cos^4 x-\cos^2 x\sin^2 x+\sin^4 x)} dx\\
&=8\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\cos^4 x-\cos^2 x\sin^2 x+\sin^4 x} dx\\
&=8\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\cos^4 x}\frac{1}{1-\tan^2x+\tan^4 x} dx\\
&=8\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{dx}{\cos^2 x}\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}\frac{1}{1-\tan^2x+\tan^4 x}\\
&=8\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} d(\tan x)\left(1+\tan^2 x\right)\frac{1}{1-\tan^2x +\tan^4 x}\\
&=8\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{(1+t^2)}{1-t^2+t^4} dt\\
&=8\int_0^{+\infty} \left(\frac{1}{t^2}+1\right)\frac{1}{\frac{1}{t^2}-1+t^2} dt\\
&=8\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{d\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)}{\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+1}\\
&=8\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{ds}{s^2+1}\\
&=8\operatorname{arctan} s|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\\
&=8\pi 
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: The third term is a repetition of the second, and there are two $dx$ in the 7th term. Otherwise, it's perfect! +1

Comment: @Nicolas fixed.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect the OP did not intend for this, but let's go with the residue theorem.  Even if we make no simplification to the denominator, things end up pretty simple.  Note that, when $z=e^{i x}$,

$$\cos^6{x}+\sin^6{x} = \left (\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2} \right )^6 - \left (\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2} \right )^6 = \frac1{16} \left (3 z^4+10+3 z^{-4} \right )$$

As usual, sub $z=e^{i x}$ in the integral; then the integral is equal to

$$-i 16 \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z} \frac2{3 z^4+10+3 z^{-4}} = -i 32 \oint_{|z|=1} dz \frac{z^3}{3 z^8+10 z^4+3}$$

The poles of the denominator occur inside the unit circle where $z_k^4=-1/3$.  By the residue theorem, the integral is equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues at these poles inside the unit circle, or

$$64 \pi \sum_{k=1}^4 \frac{z_k^3}{24 z_k^7+40 z_k^3} = 8 \pi \sum_{k=1}^4 \frac1{3 z_k^4+5} = 8 \pi (4) \left (\frac14 \right ) $$

Thus,

> $$\int_0^{2 \pi} dx \frac{2}{\cos^6{x}+\sin^6{x}} = 8 \pi$$

Comment: Always a fan of the residues method.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\cos^6x+\sin^6x=(\cos^2x)^3+(\sin^2x)^3=(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)^3-3\cos^2x\sin^2x(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)$$

$$=\dfrac{4-3\sin^22x}4=\dfrac{4(1+\cot^22x)-3}{4\csc^22x}$$

Set $\cot2x=u$

Comment: Haha I hope one day I will be able to find solutions to problems as beautifully and quickly as you do!